# Merge two columns if value is not null python

Tags: python-3.x, array-merge, multilabel-classification

I know the question may not be the hardest but I dont know why I cannot solve it:

I got two columns which I want to merge

```
    label1  label2
5   4   NaN
13  0   NaN
18  0   NaN
32  2   3
33  5   NaN
```

I want to merge them and separate them by I comma if 'label2' is not null. Else the new entry in the new column just contains the value of label1. Label1 cannot be null:

```
    label   label2 label3
5   4      NaN       [4] 
13  0      NaN       [0]          
18  0      NaN       [0]
32  2      3        [2,3]
33  5      NaN        [5]
```

The brackets around the values of my outbput column are necessary as I want to use the MultiLabelBinarizer in the next step.

Thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the dataframe and assign values to each row.

```
df['label3'] = [[row['label1'], row['label2']] if pd.notna(row['label2']) else [row['label1']] for idx, row in df.iterrows()]
```